# How to decode a MIMO stream using V-BLAST?

Tags: matlab, qpsk, quantization, mimo

I am attempting to implement the V-BLAST algorithm for MIMO streams as described by Wolniansky et al. in the following paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/738086 (I am not commenting on its useful-ness or how efficient it is, I am simply trying to implement it using the paper as written.)

The algorithm assumes the following:

- The channel, **H**, is known perfectly (or already assumed).
- It is a rich scattering environment with some number of Transmitters and some number of Receivers, but for simplicity, I myself will assume that the number of Transmitters and the number of Receivers are equal, **N**.
- The vector of received symbols follows the form **r = Ha + n**, where H is the channel, a is the encoded transmitted symbols, and n is Additive White Gaussian Noise (unit-mean).

The algorithm is described as follows in the paper:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\textrm{initialization:}\\
&(1)i\leftarrow 1\\
&(2)G_1 = H^+\\
&(3)k_1 = \textrm{argmin}_j||(G_1)_j||^2\\\\
&\textrm{recursion:}\\
&(4)w_{k_i} = (G_i)_{k_i}\\
&(5)y_{k_i} = w_{k_i}^Tr_i\\
&(6)\hat{a}_{k_i} = Q(y_{k_i})\\
&(7)r_{i+1} = r_i - \hat{a}_{k_i}(H)_{k_i}\\
&(8)G_{i+1} = H^+_{\overline{k_i}}\\
&(9)k_{i+1} = \textrm{argmin}_{j\not\in\{k_1,...,k_i\}}||(G_{i+1})_j||^2\\
&(10)i\leftarrow i+1
\end{align*}
$$

(An image from the paper can also be found [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jtw3.png))

Some definitions:

- $H^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $H$. (As in a zero-forcing decoder)
- The algorithm confusingly mixes notations. On (3), $(G_1)_j$ is the j-th row of $G_1$, but on (7), $H_{k_i}$ is the $k_i$th *column* of H.
- $Q(y)$ is the quantization (slicing) operation, according to the constellation used.

With that out of the way, I'm getting lost in the implementation. I think I understand it on a surface level, but I get tripped up in the recursion. So then, I have a few questions:

1. In my implementation with QPSK symbols and **N** = 4, $r$ is a vector of size 4x1, and $G$ is 4x4. So in line (5), what would the expected size of $y_{k_i}$ be? My MATLAB implementation gives me a 1x4 array (row vector), but I'm not 100% certain that's right.
2. What exactly is the Quantization (slicing) operation on line (6)? Is it simply demodulating whatever it is (using `qpskdemod` in MATLAB), or am I approximating the received points to its nearest points on the ideal constellation? What would the expected size of $\hat{a}$ be, a 4x1 row vector?

I think with this I'll be able to fully implement the algorithm in MATLAB. I originally wrote this question going line-by-line with my MATLAB implementation at each line of the algorithm, but the question got *really long*. I can provide my MATLAB implementation if need be. I'd also greatly appreciate anyone's attempts at a MATLAB implementation so I can fully understand the workings of this algorithm, but that isn't necessarily necessary.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In V-BLAST, $y_{ki}$ is a scalar (that is, a complex number). It is the (equalized) symbol transmitted by antenna $k_i$, with noise.

Keep in mind that all vectors are column vectors ($n \times 1$). Then, $w_{ki}$ is $4 \times 1$, and $w^T_{ki}$ is $1 \times 4$. Then, $w^T_{ki} r_i$ is $1 \times 1$, i.e. a scalar.

The "quantization" operation $Q(y_{ki})$ consists in finding the constellation element that is closest (in Euclidean distance) to $y_{ki}$. So, $Q(y_{ki})$ is the estimate of the symbol transmitted by antenna $k_i$.

Comment: That makes sense then. So as the recursion continues, the $r$ vector will continually be shaped by each subsequent element? That is to say, if $r$ began as a 4×1 vector, by the end, it will be 4×5, with the final column being the last shape?
And where would the symbols to be demodulated be stored, in $\hat{a}$ or in the final column of $r$?

Comment: No, $r$ is always $4\times1$, with one element per receiver antenna. You equalize $r$ to obtain $y$, from $y$ obtain $a$, then remove the effect of $a$ on $r$ and repeat.